# MS Access Insert results into table from sql server

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, insert

I have the below code that I'm trying to use to bring back data from sql. The connection is fine and everything works ok however, I would like to store the contents of the below code in a table in access.
Please can someone assist?

```
 Public PERSONALDBCONT As Object, _
 SQLSTR As String, SQLSTR1 As String, _
 SQLSTR2 As String, SQLSTR3 As String, _
 RecCount As String, DB As String
Function CONNECT_TO_DB()
    Set PERSONALDBCONT = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    Dim SCONN As String
SCONN = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=" & tempdb & ";Data Source=WBACUKSQLPD001;" & _
"Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=WBAC173427;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"
        PERSONALDBCONT.Open SCONN


End Function



Function CLOSE_CONNECTION_TO_SQL()

    On Error Resume Next

        PERSONALDBCONT.Close

        Set PERSONALDBCONT = Nothing

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Sub SQL_()

            Dim rs As Object

            Dim iCols As Integer

            Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

            On Error GoTo ERR



                CONNECT_TO_DB
          Dim SQLSTR As String
            SQLSTR = "Select top 1 * from sys.objects"
                rs.Open SQLSTR, PERSONALDBCONT




                Exit Sub



ERR:

            CLOSE_CONNECTION_TO_SQL

            MsgBox "There was an error at " & Stage & "." & vbNewLine & "Please see the instructions and investigate"

            If Application.Visible = False Then Application.Visible = True

            End

End Sub
```

Comment: Can it be linked into the access DB, then just simple INSERTINTO MAKE TABLE etc.

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav , I'm not sure what you mean by linked.

Comment: google linking SQL server tables to Access.

Comment: Ah, sorry . I thought you meant something similar to excel's connections. This isn't of use as I need to run a query and I dont have write access to sql therefore unable to create a proc, it's not as simple as selecting from a table.

Comment: just use a linked table in access, or get access to do it

Answer (score 0):

For your particular query that does not interact with full table, consider building the Access table beforehand that can accommodate the data from SQL Server query. Then, migrate the SQL Server recordset to Access table with either an iterative append query or recordset update:

**Append Query** *(using parameterized querydef)*

```vb
' ... same code as above ... '
Dim db As Database
Dim qdef As Querydef
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

' PREPARE SQL STATEMENT (SPECIFY PARAM NAMES AND TYPES IN FIRST LINE) '
strSQL = "PARAMETERS Col1 Text(100), Col2 Text(100), Col3 Integer, Col4 Boolean;" _
          & " INSERT INTO AccessDestinationTable (Col1, Col2, Col3)" _
          & " VALUES ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3]);"

' LOOP THROUGH SQL SERVER RS '
Do While Not SqlServerRS.EOF

   Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)
   qdef!Col1 = SqlServerRS!Col1
   qdef!Col2 = SqlServerRS!Col2
   qdef!Col3 = SqlServerRS!Col3

   qdef.Execute

   SqlServerRS.MoveNext
Loop

SqlServerRS.Close

Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = NOthing
```

**Recordset Update** *(using two open recordsets)*

```vb
' ... same code as above ... '
Dim db As Database
Dim AccessRS As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set AccessRS = db.OpenRecordset("AccessDestinationTable")

' LOOP THROUGH SQL SERVER RS '
Do While Not SqlServerRS.EOF
    ' OPEN EDIT MODE OF ACCESS RECORSET, SET VALUES TO FIELDS, APPEND ROW '
    With AccessRS
       .Edit 

       !Col1 = SqlServerRS!Col1
       !Col2 = SqlServerRS!Col2
       !Col3 = SqlServerRS!Col3

       .Update 
    End With

    SqlServerRS.MoveNext
Loop

AccessRS.Close
SqlServerRS.Close
```